# UserControl's and databound values

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

I have a User Control, which is in a templatefield on a GridView. I pass in about 6-7 properties to it, all of are bound from the data source. Here is my markup:

```
<uc1:GridMenu ID="gm1" runat="server" Total='<%# Bind("Total") %>' ....
```

Haven't copied it all as it's rather long but you can see how I'm passing the properties in. The problem is however, all the properties end up as null when they're passed through, even though I'm certainly binding the correct things. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the `Bindable` attribute to your Total property?